# Depth map to mesh

Tags: opengl, 3d, mesh, depth, point-clouds

I got greyscale depth images 0 - 255, that I want to turn into 3D meshes and then stitch them together to get one mesh. But I am not sure what to use or where to start. I read that OpenGL would be a good option.

Could anyone direct me to the right direction?

Comment: visualizing a height map mesh with opengl should be easy: check http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/beautiful_landscapes_by_means_of_height_mapping/16006/

Answer (score 2):

I haven't really used it myself but [CGAL library](http://www.cgal.org) is a pretty widely used library for meshes. (assuming you can "stich" them yourself, since this library does not provide registration/matching algorithms)

Answer (score 1):

> I read that OpenGL would be a good option.

OpenGL is a good API if you want to *draw* that heightmap. However for simply doing mesh operations it's not the right thing. There are specially suited libraries for that kind of task. [For example →GTS](http://gts.sourceforge.net/)